# Bootstrap Card Making responsive

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

May I know how will I make it responsive? or the only way is by using media query?
I am using bootstrap for cards and I want to make it responsive but when I shrink the page it just overlaps. I was wondering maybe I got my CSS mixed up. Please see below code for both css and the body. Thank you very much

```
<style>
    /* Common Styles */
    * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        text-decoration: none;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        outline: none;
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    }
    body {
        background-image: url(assets/image_bg.jpg);
        background-position: center center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-size: cover;
        background-color: #464646;
    }

    #image {
        padding: 17rem 15rem 0 25rem;
    }

    .card {
        width:16rem;
    }

    img {
        width:100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

</style>

<div id="image">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="image-column col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
          <div class="card h-100">
            <div class="card-header">
              <h3>GABEL LOFFEL</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body p-0 w-100">
              <img src="assets\image_1.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
  
        <div class="image-column col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
          <div class="card h-100 p-0">
            <div class="card-header">
              <h3>GARY GARI</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body p-0 w-100">
                <img src="assets\image_1.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="image-column col-lg-3 col-md-6">
          <div class="card h-100 p-0">
            <div class="card-header">
              <h3>IL PIATTO</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="card h-100 p-0">
                <img src="assets\image_1.jpg" alt="">

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="image-column col-lg-3 col-md-6">
            <div class="card h-100 p-0">
              <div class="card-header">
                <h3>PIERRE PLATTERS</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="card h-100 p-0">
                <img src="assets\image_1.jpg" alt="">

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the padding for `#image`,width for card from `16 rem` to `100%`.
If you are using boostrap classes for widths(here `col-lg-3 col-md-6`), then don't add a width for `card`. If you want to change the width, use % to change it.

Comment: Thank you for this. How can I change the height and width of the card to make it smaller... if I change the width to 100%. Thank you

Comment: You can change the height as you like. But change the width by adding padding to the card in percentage or px. For example, `.card {width: 100%; padding: 0 20px; height: auto;}` or  `.card {width: 100%; padding: 0 5%; height: auto;}` This should help.